# Criteria query equivalent for native query

Tags: sql, criteriaquery

how to create criteria query for this native query?

```
SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userStatus = 0 AND u.firstName LIKE " + "'" + username + "%" + "'"
```

Am I doing right?

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Users> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Users.class);
Root<Users> root = criteriaQuery.from(Users.class);
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Manager", "Sr. Manager");
Predicate predicate1=criteriaBuilder.like((root.get("firstName")), username+"%");
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(predicate1).where(root.get("designation").in(names));
```

Result:

> System considering last where condition.

Comment: use proper title for your question. Review team.

Comment: trimmed title for clarity and took it to question body